# How to embed svg into svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have to perform this task in which i have to embed one svg into another svg.
 As I am new to SVG, I have done the polygon and rectangle part but while combining these two I am facing issues. I am attaching my work up to which I have completed.

Comment: Why are you creating a vertical stack of SVGs, instead of just putting all your shapes into one big SVG?

Comment: Actually I am new to SVG. Can you refer any link for that?

Comment: I have added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to embed one svg into another svg you have to use it the same way you would use a `<symbol>` element.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let colors = [
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(255,128,0)",
  "rgb(102,204,0)",
  "rgb(102,204,0)",
  "rgb(102,178,255)"
];


let angle = Math.atan2(215,430);
let n = 0;
let offset = 10;// distance between the border of the triangle and the start of the rectangle

for(let y = 40; y < 430; y+= 40){
  
  let halfW = Math.tan(angle)*y - offset;
  let o = {
    x:430/2 - halfW,
    y: y,
    width: 2*halfW,
    height: 30,
    fill:colors[n]
  }
  
  drawRect(o, polys);
  n++;
}

function drawRect(o, parent) {

  let rect = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'rect');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      rect.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(rect);
  return rect;
}
```

```css
svg{max-width:100vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<svg width="400" height="30" y="40">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Fatality</text>
</svg>
<svg width="400" height="30" y="80">
   <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Lost Time Incidents</text>
</svg>
<svg width="400" height="30" y="120">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Restricted Work Cases</text>
</svg> 
  <svg width="400" height="30" y="160">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Medical Treatment Cases</text>
</svg>
<svg width="400" height="30" y="200">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">First Aid Cases</text>
</svg>
<svg width="400" height="30"  y="240">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">RTA Incident</text>
</svg>  
<svg width="400" height="30" y="280">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
  <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Environment Incident</text>
</svg>  
<svg width="400" height="30" y="320">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(102,204,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Near Miss</text>
</svg>  
<svg width="400" height="30" y="360">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(102,204,0);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Unsafe Acts & Conditions</text>
</svg>
<svg width="400" height="30" y="400">
  <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(102,178,255);" />
   <text x="0" y="15" fill="white">Man Hours</text>
</svg>  
  
<svg id="polys" height="430" width="430" viewBox="0 0 430 430" x="160"  >
  <polygon points="215,0, 0,430 430,430 215,0" style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:1" />

</svg>  
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But when I am trying to add rectangle inside the polygon it's not coming properly.

Comment: Please show me what you try to do. I think you may need some math.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a bunch of SVGs. Instead you should just put all your shapes into one big SVG.

Below is a quick example.  But remember, you might find it easier to just use one of the many available vector drawing apps to create your SVG.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="550" height="400">
  <g>
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Fatality</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,40)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Lost Time Incidents</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,80)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Restricted Work Cases</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,120)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Medical Treatment Cases</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,160)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">First Aid Cases</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,200)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">RTA Incident</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,240)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(255,128,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Environment Incident</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,280)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(102,204,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Near Miss</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,320)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(102,204,0);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Unsafe Acts & Conditions</text>
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,360)">
    <rect width="300" height="30" style="fill:rgb(102,178,255);" />
    <text x="10" y="20" fill="white">Man Hours</text>
  </g>

  <polygon points="350,0, 550,400, 150,400" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Inside the polygon, How to add the rectangles properly?

Comment: Just add them to the file after the triangle.  The elements in an SVG are drawn from back to front.  Anything you put after the polygon, in the file, will be drawn on top of it.

Comment: I did that but rectangle is not coming under the polygon

Comment: I have performed the task upto here:  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWH0RRGCLZTS    Can you please guide for the rectangle which I have to insert under the polygon.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What rectangle "under the polygon"?  What are you confused about?  If you mean the rectangles inside the triangle, then just add some more `<rect>` elements.